# Not seeing the real IP in X-Forwarded-For with the basic setup of Traefik in Docker?

Tags: docker, traefik

Fell in love with Traefik's presentation on youtube, so I've been trying to set it up. My docker server is on 192.168.0.23.

Even when querying from another host from my LAN (192.168.0.144), I am always getting the internal IP in the X-Forwarded-For...

```
curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://192.168.0.23:8880
```

shows

```
Hostname: 20f76fbc038e
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.22.0.2
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.docker.localhost
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 172.22.0.1
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.docker.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: c40ba22259b6
X-Real-Ip: 172.22.0.1
```

The same thing happens when calling from another network through the public IP, still seeing `X-Forwarded-For: 172.22.0.1`

My docker-compose is one of the basic examples...

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "8880:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
```

Am I missing something? I'd expect to at least get the IP of the host initiating the request in the list of X-Forwarded-For, as I've been seeing all over examples in the web...

The weird thing is that the IP that shows in the forwarded field is the IP of the server in the docker network, which would make sense when the curl is executed from the server itself, not from another host in the same network or through the internet...

Comment: It looks like the Docker engine doesn't pass the original IP address to Traefik, instead replacing it with its own IP within the Docker network. If that is true, then using a different proxy server as a container within Docker would give the same problems. I can't find mentions of this issue, so I cannot tell what happens. I use Traefik outside of Docker and don't see the issue, but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Have you solve this problem right now? @doudou91 could you show me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in kubernetes. We however solved the problem by adding the following global arguments.

```bash
globalArguments:
  - "--api.insecure=true"
  - "--entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
  - "--entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
```